# Why the sequence $(E_n)$ exists

Tags: measure-theory, bochner-spaces

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space and $(X,\|.\|)$ be a reflexive Banach space.

[image]

I did not understand why the sequence **$(E_n)$** **exists**.

An idea please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply take
$$
E_n =\{x : \|f(x)\| + \|g(x)\| \leq n \}.
$$

Comment: Why $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}{E_n}=\Omega$?

Comment: @kaka: Given $x$, then $\|f(x)\|+\|g(x)\|$ is a real number, so you can take some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ bigger than this number.

Comment: but if $\|f(x)\|=+\infty$

Comment: @kaka: What's your definition of a (measurable) vector values function?